# Platform.getBundle(Activator.PLUGIN_ID) returns null

Tags: plugins, junit, junit4

I have a function for ex

```
public void func {
  ....
  ....
  URL url = Platform.getBundle(Activator.PLUGIN_ID).getEntry("config");
  ....
  ....
}
```

Now I am writing Junit test case for the above function which is in different test plugin.
When I call func in my junit test method I am getting null pointer exception.

I tried printing

```
Platform.getBundle(Activator.PLUGIN_ID) which returns null
Platform.isRunning() which returns false.
```

Please let me know how to solve this? What I can do so that my JUnit testcase is successful.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can move Platform.getBundle(Activator.PLUGIN_ID) to a method and stub that method for your testing

Comment: Could you please elaborate it more. I am new to stub and mocks. I don't know how to stub it. A logical code would help.

Comment: Basically move your "Platform.getBundle(Activator.PLUGIN_ID)" to a method and ovverride that method during testing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Just a Pseudo Code...

      private Platform platform;

      public void func() {
              //....
              //....
              URL url = getPlatForm().getEntry("config");
              //....
              //....
            }

        public Platform getPlatForm() {
            return platform.getBundle(Activator.PLUGIN_ID);
        } 


In your testcase,

   override the getPlatForm() method with a mock/stub.


  Class yourClass = new yourClass() {
   @override
   public Platform getPlatForm() {
        return mock/stub!!;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got it. I override the method and I am returning the required URL.

Comment: I have one more doubt. What if the call URL url = Platform.getBundle(Activator.PLUGIN_ID).getEntry("config"); is there in the constructor??? How can we solve it. Putting it in a method and call it in constructor is not a good idea I believe.

Comment: Most place all such statements appear in a init()... In your case - PowerMock can Mock constructor. You can try that.